# Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@localhost'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

So I have an issue with docker-compose and rabbitmq.

I run docker-compose up. Everything spins up. Docker-compose:

```
services:
  rabbitmq3:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    hostname: "localhost"
    command: rabbitmq-server
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
```

Then I do `sudo rabbitmqctl status` to check connection with node. I get this error:

```
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@localhost'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@localhost
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@localhost]

rabbit@localhost:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on localhost
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on localhost
  * suggestion: start the node

Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-25456-rabbit@localhost'
 * effective user's home directory: /Users/olof.grund
 * Erlang cookie hash: d1oONiVA/qogGxkf6vs9Rw==
```

When I do it in the container `docker-compose exec -T rabbitmq3 rabbitmqctl status` it works.

Do I need to expose something from docker somehow? Some rabbitmq client or node maybe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rabbitmq uses Erlang's distribution protocol, which requires port 4369 open for the EPMD (Erlang Port Mapper Daemon), expose it in the docker-compose and stop the EPMD running in your host.

Answer (score 0):

I used all the tips that I have found in other sources. (adding IP to /etc/hosts/, restarts of containers, services). Took me a day to finally get this to work and it boils down to this.

```
<wait for 60secs since the rabbit container has been started>
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl reset
rabbitmqctl force_boot
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Docker executes commands instantaneously, especially in docker build commands that are detached and do not wait around, sometimes executing `rabbitmqctl` commands fails because you do not wait a few seconds. Consider putting a `sleep 15` and then executing the command.